# PBS or TBS, where cannot use each buffers?

Tags: biochemistry

As you know, Tris buffered saline and Phosphate buffered saline is multipurpose. For finding each buffer's use, there's so many use experiment for PBS and TBS. TBS uses for western blotting, and PBS uses for cell culture.

but some experiment never use PBS and some experiment never use TBS, I want to ask this situation which when you use TBE but never use PBS, and the opposite situation(use TBS but never use PBS), For example, When you western-blotting with alkaline phosphatase never use PBS and PBS-T. this case, phosphate inhibits AP, and amine-coupling with NHS-EDC, never use Tris buffer because it have primary amine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question.

The buffer used in a given experiment depends on the requirements and limitations of the experiment itself. You just have to look at the properties of the buffer, and if it is relevant to your experiment.

You just gave two great examples... are you just looking for more examples of experiments when one would not use phosphate buffer vs Tris buffer?

PBS is supposed to closely mimic/represent the osmolarity of a cell, and buffer from pH = 7.0 to 9.0. Tris also buffers around neutral pH. It is pretty cheap, but as you've stated, has primary amine groups that are nucleophilic and thus interfere with certain experiments like disuccinimidyl suberate crosslinking, etc.